# Cannot fetch room notes through EWS API

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I want to fetch the field `Notes` for a room with EWS API.

This field is present on Outlook, but I cannot find a way to fetch it with the API.

So far, I have tried to fetch it with:

```
NameResolutionCollection nameResolutions = service.resolveName(room.getName(), ResolveNameSearchLocation.DirectoryThenContacts, true);
```

but the `Notes` field is not present in the returned contact.

I have also tried to fetch it with

```
Contact roomContact = Contact.bind(service, new ItemId(room.getId()), new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, ContactSchema.Body));
// roomContact.getBody().toString() should contains the 'Notes' field
```

However, the room have not any ItemId: `room.getId()` returns `null`

At last, I have tried to load the property with `nameResolution.getContact().load(new PropertySet(ItemSchema.Body))` and this time I have the exception `InvalidOperationException: This operation can't be performed because this service object doesn't have an Id`.

Do you have an idea on how I can fetch the `Notes` field of a room ? I might also be interested in a way to find a room ID.

Comment: It is a very open question and not well formatted

Comment: Does your comment add any value to the question or provide any help to improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the PropertySet Overload in ResolveName to specify you want all properties returned by ResolveName (this will also return the Userphoto if its enabled) eg

```
        PropertySet AllProps = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
        NameResolutionCollection ncCol = service.ResolveName("User@domain.com", ResolveNameSearchLocation.DirectoryOnly, true, AllProps);
        foreach (NameResolution nr in ncCol)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(nr.Contact.Notes);
        }
```

You can't do a Load on a Contact returned from the GAL because this isn't and Exchange Store Object (eg it doesn't have an EWSId).

Cheers
Glen